# What Wordpress Template for this type of web?

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, slideshow

i want web on wordpress which look like this web.

```
http://www.landrover.co.uk/index.html
```

I want it for representation commercial use. Existing this type template free or paid? I dont want videos in slideshow like here, only this structure, slideshow etc. I jus want to search template where is all this possible edit via wordpress withou html or with basic html experience

Is here some template for use? Thank you for tips, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: may be this is not the right place for this work. We are sorry.

Comment: You will just have to look through different templates and find what you wan't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement I will suggest you to use Pique theme in wordpress. It is somehow similar to what you want.
Here is link to check: 
https://theme.wordpress.com/themes/pique/
You can also check Gateway theme:
https://theme.wordpress.com/themes/gateway/
(Both are free theme)

Comment: Thanks very much i will try these Themes!